# django-python ordenar json

Tags: python, json, django, lista

django y no se como ordenar ésta lista por orden del titulo.

estoy usando:

```
nuevo_json_array = sorted(json_array, key=itemgetter('oportunidad_json'))

  [  
   {  
      'pk': 1
      'oportunidad_json':OrderedDict([ 
        ('id',38441),
         ('titulo',   'Barelona'),  ]),
      'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00',
      'clase':'A'
     },
     {  
      'pk': 2
      'oportunidad_json':OrderedDict([ 
        ('id',1223),
         ('titulo',   'Alicante'),  ]),
      'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00',
      'clase':'B'
     },
      {  
      'pk': 3
      'oportunidad_json':OrderedDict([ 
        ('id',577),
         ('titulo',   'Madrid'),  ]),
      'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00',
      'clase':'C'
     }
]
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> unorderable types: collections.OrderedDict() < collections.OrderedDict()
> ```

Comment: puedes colocar el json original?

Comment: Esto es lo que recibe el frontend, [{  
      'pk': 1,
      'oportunidad_json':{
     'id': 38441,
   'titulo': 'Barelona',
  },
  'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00'
  'clase':'A'
     },
     {  
      'pk': 2,
      'oportunidad_json':{
        'id':1223,
        'titulo': 'Alicante',
  }
      'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00',
      'clase':'B'
     },
      {  
      'pk': 3,
      'oportunidad_json':{ 
        'id':577,
        'titulo':'Madrid'
  }
      'fecha':'2018-10-30T02:00:00',
      'clase':'C'
 }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo en tu pregunta, quieres ordenar el JSON por orden (alfabético) de `titulo`, que se encuentra contenido en `oportunidad_json`. Para ello le puedes indicar que tu `key` sea `titulo` mediante una función `lambda` de la siguiente manera:

In[1] >> `nuevo_json_array = sorted(json_array, key=lambda t: t['oportunidad_json']['titulo'])`

In[2] >> `nuevo_json_array`

Out[2]>>
`[{'clase': 'B',
  'fecha': '2018-10-30T02:00:00',
  'oportunidad_json': OrderedDict([('id', 1223), ('titulo', 'Alicante')]),
  'pk': 2},
 {'clase': 'A',
  'fecha': '2018-10-30T02:00:00',
  'oportunidad_json': OrderedDict([('id', 38441), ('titulo', 'Barelona')]),
  'pk': 1},
 {'clase': 'C',
  'fecha': '2018-10-30T02:00:00',
  'oportunidad_json': OrderedDict([('id', 577), ('titulo', 'Madrid')]),
  'pk': 3}]`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! no sabes las horas que pasé intentándolo, de verdad muchas gracias. Me falta mucho por aprender en Python :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido de ayuda :)